# Sqlite3. It is necessary to obtain the first occurrence of a value under a certain condition

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I have a sqlite database of the form:

```
    c.execute('''
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS order_info (
            id                  INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
            name                TEXT NOT NULL,
            surname             TEXT NOT NULL,
            email               TEXT NOT NULL,
            date                TEXT NOT NULL,
            time                TEXT NOT NULL,
            phone               TEXT NOT NULL,
            contact             TEXT NOT NULL,
            idd                 TEXT NOT NULL,
            doc                 TEXT NOT NULL,
            problem             TEXT NOT NULL,
            status              TEXT,
            is_send             INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 
        )
    ''')
```

**Task:** I need to change the order 'status' field, where the condition is: (doc = doc_id) and the NULL value in the 'status' field is encountered for the first time from the beginning

```
    c.execute('UPDATE order_info SET status = ? WHERE doc = ? (#condition#)', (status, doc_id)
```

**#condition#** - here I need to make conditions for finding the first occurrence of NULL in the status row where the value is doc = doc_id

**Example:**
doc_id = 3;
the status field should change only at the 6th id

**image of database:**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KTHga.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to update the row with `id` equal to the minimum `id` where `doc = ?` and status is `null`:

```
UPDATE order_info 
SET status = ? 
WHERE id = (SELECT MIN(id) FROM order_info WHERE doc = ? AND status IS NULL)
```